# Stress test mvc application

Tags: manual-testing, jmeter, load-testing, visualstudio, stress-testing

I am new to web performance testing. I was looking for tools with which I could stress test my mvc application written in c# and see how it performs under severe load. I want to simulate approximately 10000 virtual users. I found many people have mentioned JMeter for stress testing.

1. However, I could not find if I can simulate these many users with JMeter and how many machines do I need for this.
2. Another option  which is paid is Visual studio ultimate. This one is pretty expensive for a very small organization that has couple of (not so big) applications to test.  But still I want to know that if I want to use  few 100 machines(available with the company) in stress testing my application, one license of VS utlimate is sufficient?
3. Any other suggestions for tools that can provide the said number of virtual users would be very helpful

Comment: RE JMeter.  How many machines depends on the web site.  You'll need to try it for yourself.  You also need to be more precise about the requirements: 10000 simultaneous users?  10000 users over the course of a minute?  Or an hour?

Comment: @user246 : 10000 users over a course of about an hour. But I also need to test 3000 simultaneous users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jmeter is best option for load testing of any web application and database.

1- To simulate 10000 virtual users , if you want to use jmeter then you will have to use cloud system like http://blazemeter.com/. Because for this type of high load testing cloud system is only capable.

2 -  About another tool , You are right those are very expensive. So I suggest you to use above if appropriate for you.

Comment: Can I simulate 3000 simultaneous users using only Jmeter ? Can distributed testing in Jmeter serve this purpose?

Comment: Actually Jmeter does not have any issue with lots of user. It is depends on your server capacity , free physical memory of your machine on which you are running jmeter. Yes you can do it with distributed system.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a free trial of our tool called [StresStimulus](http://www.stresstimulus.com/), which includes unlimited number of virtual users and unlimited number of agent machines. 
StresStimulus is more lightweight than VS Ultimate and can emulate about 40% more users on the same hardware. Re: pricing, StresStimulus' weekly or a monthly licenses are substantially less costly than VS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a free performance testing solution capable of simulating 10 000 users the options are in:

- [Grinder](http://grinder.sourceforge.net/)
- [Tsung](http://tsung.erlang-projects.org/)
- [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/)

Tsung is known for better support of multithreading so you'll need to have less machines to produce the load, however it is Linux-only and doesn't have a GUI.

I believe that [Open Source Load Testing Tools: Which One Should You Use?](http://blazemeter.com/blog/open-source-load-testing-tools-which-one-should-you-use) guide will help you to choose the right option.

N.B. 10 000 virtual users don't necessarily stand for 10 000 testing threads.

Let.s imagine that

1. Each user needs to "think" 15 seconds before each action
2. Average response time of your system is 5 seconds

It means that each user will be able to execute 60 / (15 + 5) = 3 requests per minute.

In that case 10 000 users will execute 30 000 requests per minute, 30 000 / 60 = 500 requests per second.

So you can simulate 10 000 users using only **500 concurrent threads**, even a single machine can produce such a load.

Comment: Can you please explain about how can a single machine produce that load per second?

Comment: For JMeter just follow steps from [JMeter Performance and Tuning Tips](http://blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-performance-and-tuning-tips), running it in non-GUI mode with all the listeners disabled and reasonable minimum of post processors and assertions should be enough to produce 500 concurrent requests using i.e. Core i5 laptop with 8Gb RAM